# Is TC Helicon VoiceLive 2 good in the studio for vocals?

Tags: live, studio

I want to know if anyone has tried the famous [TC Helicon VoiceLive 2](http://www.tc-helicon.com/products/voicelive-2/) in the studio. This effect pedal is made for live performance but the website say that it can also be used for studio. I can't find good article on this on the internet. Did anyone try it out? If so:

-What are the positive/negative things about your experience.
-How did you plug it to your computer (USB, etc..)

I want fact, I don't want to know that you have a big studio with effects better than that. I want to know things like "it makes noise" or "the levels are very bad", etc.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to figure out *why it's good* or are you trying to figure out *if there are any problems with it*? I was going to edit your question to clarify but I realized I wasn't entirely sure what the point of the question was.

Comment: In fact I'm searching for the 2 options, bad thing and good thing but it must be a fact.

Comment: there are many articles on [gearslutz](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/) that will answer your question or at least lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you use it and the intent.

You will get the most versatility and flexibility by recording your signal with no processing and then adding processing later. If you go this path, you may find that even inexpensive plug ins may provide more of the sound you desire than than the Voicelive 2. I find the Voicelive 2's reverb to sound thin and brittle, and the chorus does not have enough depth, which surprises me because TC's choruses are amazing (I know that they are essentially two different companies).

Now, if you are using it for the looping or just trying to replicate how you use it live, I say why not print with effects? You can avoid at least one D to A stage by going in and out with the SPDIF, or I guess you could use USB, but a lot of DAWs don't like more than one audio interface.